# Get system time in millisecond using Buttons while recording video

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

I  am recording a `video` using `camera2api` with a `button` to start the recording.Now when the recording starts, i need to get system time in milliseconds only if i press a specific button(other than the start rec button
) .

If not the system time, then at least the record time of the video being recorded.

The time should be stored only if i press the specific button. I have tried using  `system.currentTimeMillis()` and `systemclock.elapsedtime()`, but once the recording starts and then i press the specific button to record time without stopping recorded ,it doesn't store any time details and shows 0.

Below is the code which i am using to store time:

```
case R.id.video: {
            if (mIsRecordingVideo) {
                stopRecordingVideo();
            } else {
                startTSRecordingVideo();
                starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick:time "+starttime);
                switch (view.getId()){
                    case R.id.stop:{
                        stoptime= SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()-starttime;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick:timefor slowstop "+stoptime);
                    }
                    break;
                    case R.id.timeshift:{
                        slstarttime=SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-starttime;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick:timefor slowstart"+slstarttime);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Please tell me, how to get the time without affect the recording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misplaced the `stop` and `timeshift` button event and it will not get called. It should be directly on the switch case.

Try this.

```
case R.id.video:
    if (mIsRecordingVideo) {
       stopRecordingVideo();
     } else {
       startTSRecordingVideo();
       starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick:time "+starttime);
     }
     break;
case R.id.stop:
        stoptime= SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()-starttime;
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick:timefor slowstop "+stoptime);        
     break;
case R.id.timeshift:
        slstarttime=SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-starttime;
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick:timefor slowstart"+slstarttime);
     break;
```

Comment: Thanks @Jaymin, i tried what u suggested, in logs i'm getting this "D/Camera2VideoFragment: onClick:timefor slowstop **0**
D/Camera2VideoFragment: onClick:timefor slowstart **-1482516564434**"

Comment: ,button timeshift is getting negative long number when pressed and after pressing timeshift it gives the time but stop button is not giving any time as of now

Comment: replace `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` with `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` and then tell what you get in the `Log`

Comment: i replaced with SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()  but still i'm getting the same log as i have posted before.

Comment: still you are getting minus timestamp

Comment: hi @Jaymin now i have got the system time but i used System.currenttimemillis().  Thank you for solving this issue